# CSS - Reset causing Error with my other tags

Tags: html, css

I am making a hangman game.  And I am working on styling everything.  I am including CSS reset in my HTML and I think it is causing my tags to error out.  Like my H1 tag isn't working now.  Any thoughts?

The H1 tag should make my text big and bold.  However that is not working.  The linked stylesheet I am using is empty right now.  When I remove the CSS Reset link the H1 then works correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hangman</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="gamebox">
   <h1>Hang-Person</h1>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: reformat your question please. Not working means ?

Comment: What does it mean when a tag "errors out"?  If this is a CSS question, you should publish the _relevant_ CSS.

Comment: What does the css look like? What do you mean by the tags error out? Which tag doesn't work? What does your file hierarchy look like?

Comment: Thanks - Just edited it.  Hopefully that is a little clearer.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a reset stylesheet in the first place? I dare say you don't.

Comment: Guys - Thanks for all the help.  Rookie developer here.  I was running the Css Reset without adding bootstrap.  So I was trying to work off a totally reset CSS file.  Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last script tag is outside the body tag. It should be inside

Comment: While absolutely true, this is not the cause of the OP's problem; the reset stylesheet is. Apparently it is one of those reset stylesheets that makes everything look like plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware to **not repeat** the same properties for each object in CSS.
Example:
In *reset.css*:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

And in *style.css*:

```
body {
   margin: 20px;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

It might cause the browser to get confused, I recommend you to do CSS reset in only one of your stylesheets. You can do it in the other one as well, but it won't be as efficient.
Here you have the universal CSS reset code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

After this, you can specify the margin or padding to every element, although it violates the **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.
**CSS Working example**:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.object1 {
    padding: 70px;
}
```

It would be more helpful if you post the CSS code for better answers.
Last but not least, the last `<script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>` tag should be inside the `body` tag.

***EDIT***: try with the *universal CSS reset code* and keep the linked stylesheet.